# MongoDB mapReduce: Emit a DBRef oid as key

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, key

I need to maintain an application where data stored in MongoDB, and I'm fluent yet with the mapReduce syntax.

I want to make a mapReduce operation where the emitted key is the *ID* of a *DBRef*, not it's value. I clearly understand from [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/) that for parallelism reason one mustn't and can't access the DB.

So my collection documents are like that:

```
{
  _id: "66f072b8-2422-4022-826b-b20b832a1ee6",
  _class: "com.foo.bar",
  foo_bar: 1,
  user: {
    "$dbref": {
      namespace: "user",
      oid: "6cd0dac5-a511-48b1-b437-318ad74061a5"
    }
  }
}
```

The *current* mapReduce is like that:

```
db.myCollection.mapReduce(
  function () {
      if (this.foo_bar > 0) {
          emit(this.user, this.foo_bar);
      }
  },
  function (key, values) {
      var sum = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
          sum += values[i];
      }
      return sum;
  },

  {
    "out" : { "inline" : 1} 
  }
)
```

There is a lot of documents and the loading between AWS and MongoHQ is taking a lot of time. I would like to be able to use *user$id as a key*, instead of the DBRef's document.

I've tested with the following but without success:

1. emit(**this.user.id**, this.foo_bar);
2. emit(**this.user.oid**, this.foo_bar);
3. emit(**this.user._id**, this.foo_bar);
4. emit(**this.user.dbref.id**,this.foo_bar);
5. emit(**this.user.dbref.oid**, this.foo_bar);
6. emit(**this.user.dbref._id**, this.foo_bar);
7. emit(**this.user['$dbref'].oid**, this.foo_bar); (as per Sammaye suggestion in comments)

What's the correct syntax?

Comment: `this.user['$dbref'].oid`

Comment: Nope. Mongo gives: Thu Jan 30 23:22:52.584 map reduce failed:{
 "errmsg" : "exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'oid' of undefined near '**['$dbref'].oid, this. foo_bar)**'  (line 3)",
 "code" : 16722,
 "ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:970 - any suggestion @cubitouch?

Comment: I think the biggest problem here is that the Java driver have not standardised their dbrefs, I assume you use java from the other details in the document

Comment: We indeed use Java (Spring MongoDB). The output I'm giving you is by using **mongo** cli on OSX.

Comment: Is the dbref ever not set?

Comment: Never, it's an required "ownership".

Comment: I just doubled check with a `find.(user:{$exists:false})` to be sure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46467/discussion-between-gammatora-and-sammaye)

Comment: wait thats not the right query, query for `find({user:null})`

Comment: Woops :) Just tried with it but I still have `No documents found`.

Comment: Hmm this is making me think a little now

Comment: Our MongoHQ instance is running on `2.4.6` by the way.

Comment: Hang on Ima test this, there is no explanation why this shouldn't work

Comment: HAHAHA I can't test it, the shells own DBRef is different to Javas and of course new rules in the shell and drivers dictate you can't insert fields with $ at the start of them

Comment: No way...! I'm really unlucky with this problem.

Comment: @Gammatora Yes, I would suggest you not to add tags in your question titles.

Comment: Are you certain that is the format of your document (i.e. that is the results you see from a `find()` in the `mongo` shell? I believe `$dbref` should be an invalid key and would expect this to be a [`$ref` value](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref) instead. If the value is `$dbref` as you suggest, then I expect Sammaye's reference should work: `this.user["$dbref"].oid`.  If it's actually a DBref() you should be able to use `this.foo.user.$id`.

Comment: Normally you would be able to use `printjson(this)` in your `map()` function to print a JSON version of the document you are receiving to the `mongod` log. I'm not sure if that's an option for you with MongoHQ, but you could always mongodump that collection and test with a local instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real answer here I believe is revisit your schema design. It is noted that the Spring data approach is more skewed to a traditional relational design rather than the dynamic document structure MongoDB provides.

That said, here is a [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/IujsnO7GLSE) with more explanation and alternatives from the MongoDB community manager. Follow the notes and the link contained in that response.

The only approach other than re-design, and this is really only a workaround to actually doing the re-design is to **pre-join** the data using the **output** from map reduce. This is an incremental step. The resulting collection will allow you to query the properties of the sub-documents without pulling each document down over the wire.

As another note a similar output option is set to be added to the Aggregation Framework pipeline in the next release of MongoDB.

Comment: I completely agrees with you, the model need to be redesigned ASAP to be more document oriented. It's currently impossible to do so. The [link](http://tebros.com/2011/07/using-mongodb-mapreduce-to-join-2-collections/) you pointed to is interesting BUT the given solution couldn't be applied: I **can't** access the DBRef identifier at mapReduce time!

Comment: How does the **answer** not apply? You cannot do joins, you cannot access the properties of the referenced object without loading it. You need to **prejoin** the data in another collection. Edit applied to clarify

Comment: He's not looking to JOIN he is looking to just get the `oid` out of the object

Comment: @Sammaye the oid if the **Linked** object from the DBRef is called a join. The purpose of DBRef has been [explained](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/IujsnO7GLSE) as a client side operation only. If you want to get at the data from those linked documents without pulling everything over the wire (which has been stated as the intention [re: data centers]) and processing in the client, then you have to combine the results into a collection on the server you can use.

Comment: There is no other answer to wait for. The DBRef contains no other information than which document _id in which collection, and possibly which database. The only way you get the full detail of the referenced document is by reading from the source collection. Hence the work around to not re-designing to dump the **combined** results into a workable collection.

Comment: The oid is in the parent document, not the child document, it can be pulled out easily enough

Comment: @Sammaye Dude, you haven't proposed an answer and your comments asserting this have already been rejected. You clearly are not understanding the differential between client and server side interpretation of DBRef. Please stop flaming as it is unproductive to this guy understanding what he has to do to solve his problem

Comment: I proposed an answer which according to the rules of JavaScript should have worked however, I cannot test his particular case due to upgrades within the latter versions of MongoDB which sto certain actions, i.e. placing `$` prefixed fields into the document. Since I cannot, currently, install an earlier version of MongoDB it was the best I could do

Comment: A DBRef houses the child id within the parent document, this is how it works within the client side helper, it uses the nested child id within the parent document, along with the database name and collection name (also stored i the parent document) to resolve a lazy loaded JOIN. The OP is looking to retrieve that ID stored in the parent document to be used within Map Reduce

Comment: The oid of the `user` object is not a join, it is an embedded object within the parent document which when resolved client side is used to indentify a related record.

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance of the answer. I did redesign the DB to be NoSQL-compliant. Failed to access the oid field no matter how I tried. Thanks to both of you (Neil Lunn link quite useful too!).

Comment: @Gammatora Sorry for the flood of comments on this issue. Your Question title was a bit misleading as plenty of people kept saying that the $oid was just there. A similar explaination was offered here today: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21592353/2313887

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for the tip. That's what I figured out.